# Problem accessing keychain certificate via ssh in macOS Sonoma

Tags: appium, keychain, codesign, xcode15, macos-sonoma

I'm running iOS mobile automation tests using appium on macOS Sonoma. When I connect to Mac via SSH, I cannot access my certificate in the login keychain. There is no problem when using the Mac terminal. I tried the temporary methods below and could not find the exact cause of the problem. Can you help?
**security -v unlock-keychain -p $PASSWORD "/Users/$USER/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db"** --> works only for a single session, the problem persists in a different session.

Adding this command to bash_profile or bashrc is not a definitive solution.

When I codesign manually via ssh, I get the **errSecInternalComponent** error. When I try it on the Mac terminal, there is no problem.

Appium version : 2.4.1
Xcode version : 15.2
MacOS sonoma : 14.2.1

Can you help me? Thanks

There was no problem in pre-Sonoma versions, but after the upgrade I started having access problems.

Answer (score 0):

You may be facing a similar issue that I have been facing recently.
You have to unlock the keychain in each session. For me it was before `xcodebuild build` and `xcodebuild archive` commands (they rested in different bash scripts).
And also move all Apple certificates (including intermediate) to a System keychain as mentioned in this thread: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/69464.
Feel free to update if this helped or not.